# Call multiple controller methods from different routes in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've a question :

I would like to know if is there a way to call multiple controller's methods in a view from different routes, i'll explain :

I want to use the "Default" route and a new one i've created :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Index", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "TranslateText",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{stringToTranslate}/{from}/{to}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Translation", action = "TranslateText", stringToTranslate = "", from = "", to = "" }
        );
```

I have multiple items in my view who's using the Default route, but i have one who's using the "TranslateText" route.

i'm calling it in the view like that :

```
<legend id="UploadCVLabel" style="color: #FF6600;">@(Url.Action("TranslateText", "Translation", "Upload your CV (Drag & Drop)", "en", "de" }; ))
                    </legend>
```

And in my controller, here is the signature of the method :
    public JsonResult TranslateText(string stringToTranslate = "", string inputLangCode = "en", string outputLangCode = "fr")

I would like to know if there is a way to call them both in the same view, because if i'm putting the "TranslateText" route before the "Default" one, it only call the "TranslateText" method without parameters and return an empty JSON.
If i'm doing the opposite ("Default" before "TranslateText" route), it will never call the last route ("TranslateText").

Thanks

P.S : I'm new in the MVC world :)

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in Url.Action() syntax, use following:

```
@(Url.Action("TranslateText", "Translation", new {stringToTranslate = "Upload your CV (Drag & Drop)", from = "en", to = "de" } ))
```

Change method signature to:

```
public ActionResult TranslateText(string stringToTranslate = "", string from = "en", string to = "fr")
{
  ...
  return View(...);
}
```

And put your custom route before Default

Comment: It displays me in my view this : "/Translation/TranslateText?stringToTranslate=Upload%20your%20CV%20(Drag%20%26%20Drop)&from=en&to=de" instead of the translation...The weirdest thing is in debug, it won't pass in the "TranslateText" method, whereas if i put the "TranslateText" route before the "Default", it debugs...

Comment: It won't work either...But if I put the Default route first and set "@(Html.Action("TranslateText", "Translation", new { stringToTranslate = "Upload your CV (Drag & Drop)", from = "en", to = "de" } ))" instead of "@(Url.Action("TranslateText", "Translation", new { stringToTranslate = "Upload your CV (Drag & Drop)", from = "en", to = "de" } ))" it works it give me the translation, but it renders me the complete page in HTML-tags format, not in graphic, how could i correct this please ?

Comment: Change signature of your TranslateText method, you should return ActionResult. And in this method you should return a View(). Updates are above

Comment: Ok, but i have to create a TranslateText View and render it into the other view right ? because i have this error : The view 'TranslateText' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Translation/TranslateText.aspx
~/Views/Translation/TranslateText.ascx
~/Views/Shared/TranslateText.aspx
~/Views/Shared/TranslateText.ascx
~/Views/Translation/TranslateText.cshtml
~/Views/Translation/TranslateText.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/TranslateText.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/TranslateText.vbhtml

Comment: Here is the answer in an other link : [Answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973443/call-multiple-controller-methods-from-different-routes-in-a-view-part2